# Object leaving the ground conditions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

I was wondering and having a hard time trying to figure out the conditions for a moving object to leave the ground when in comes with some velocity and go uphill a certain curve.

I started with the knowledge that the normal force would be zero when the object leaves the ground. But it didn't get me much.

**There is another way of thinking about this kind of problem?**

Another ideia I have was that a condition for a object leaves the ground in $x'$ is that the ground $f(x)$ is lower in $x+\epsilon$ than the projectile path $z(x)$ in $x'+\epsilon$ initiating at that point $x'$.

Does it makes sense?

Comment: *I started with the knowledge that the normal force would be zero when the object leaves the ground. But it didn't get me much.* Why not? It seems like the right approach to me.

Comment: If you don't use the centripetal force to go this problem, it get cubbesome, at least for me.